# Java ArrayList with condition

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I have a question about if condition in ArrayList, Please see code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<BankAccount>accounts=new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        BankAccount Mary=new BankAccount(1,50);
        BankAccount Lucy=new BankAccount(2,100);
        BankAccount Lily=new BankAccount(3,20);
        BankAccount Pete=new BankAccount(4,200);
        BankAccount Paul=new BankAccount(5,30);

        accounts.add(Mary);
        accounts.add(Lucy);
        accounts.add(Lily);
        accounts.add(Pete);
        accounts.add(Paul);

        double min = accounts.get(0).getBalance();
        int poorestPerson = accounts.get(0).getAccountNumber();
        for(BankAccount a:accounts) {
            if(a.getBalance()<min) {
                poorestPerson=a.getAccountNumber();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Poorest person is "+poorestPerson);
    }
}
```

The result is always 5, but the correct print should be 3, when I add :

```
  poorestPerson=a.getAccountNumber();
  **min=a.getBalance();**
```

It prints right answer, my question is how does this command vary the result?Cheers.

I have understood how does this command work, but could someone please explain if I do not write **min=a.getBalance();** , how does the condition work and why does it print the last element?

Comment: You never reset the `min` to the smallest amount.

Comment: You must update 'min' as @SotiriosDelimanolis said

Comment: Check your logic once again. It will always print the last value which is lesser than the first value. The reason is you are not resetting the minimum value. AS your self have mentioned in the post, you should update the min value once you find the new one.

Comment: Thanks guys, so if I do not update, why does it print the last one?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis should write it as an answer and get it validated as he gave the answer first.

Comment: @WangPeiTheDancer Because the last element in the list is smaller than the original `min` and since it's the last to be evaluated, you'll always see that one.

Comment: Because the last element is '30' which is below '50'. If you change last element to '60', then answer will always be 3, which is the last value below '50'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double min=accounts.get(0).getBalance();
```

This line gets the first element as reference to the smallest value in the list. Either the algorithm finds a smaller value than this one, or just returns the first one.

You could even set `double min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

If you don't update that value each time your find a smaller one, then there's not point in searching for it, since you already have it (first element in list).

```
min=a.getBalance();
```

Thus, this line is required.

Comment: Please explain your downvote. Furthermore, pay attention to what he asked in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

this should fix your problem

```
 if(a.getBalance()<min){
            poorestPerson=a.getAccountNumber();
            min=a.getBalance();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't set min when changing poorestPerson in the if in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does check and get 3 but after that when it reaches the 5th, it also checks if 30 < 50 which is true. You need to update **min** so that it can verify against all the min's that come to be true in comparisons.

```
if(a.getBalance()<min){
    poorestPerson=a.getAccountNumber();
    min = a.getBalance(); // the new min
}
```

Comment: It's _not_ true that 50 < 30.

Comment: without updating the min, why does it print the last one? How the condition work if it is without updating the min?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It's 30 < 50. Not other way around.

Comment: @Sajal I know what it _ought_ to be, but your answer says "it also checks if 50 < 30 which is true."

Comment: @WangPeiTheDancer Because you are always comparing against the first balance at index 0 which is 50. So you are comparing 50 < 50, 100 < 50, 20 < 50, 200 < 50, 30 < 50. Only 20 < 50 and 30 < 50 are true. Since you are not updating the min, you are getting the last one at 5th. You can put a print statement for you to see.